# sqlite database lock

Tags: c#

I am developing c# application , in which the backend is sqlite.
multiple threads are running at a time.so when i perform CRUD operation it always shows me the error message as database is locked.When i perform the Crud operation same time sync  process(creating local db from remote db) is going on,in this case the lock error always occurs.it happens when cmd.ExecuteNonquery method is calling.

Server is console application.Client is windows application here sync will happen means from server it takes remote database and  create local databse and insert data to local db.

Through server we can perform CRUD operation to remote databse.This will throw lock error.
For crud operation we using simple UI IN browser.

can anyone plz help me in this, coz this very critical for me.

Thank you

regards
sangita

Comment: not enough information to answer...

Comment: Server is console application.Client is windows application here sync will happen means from server it takes remote database and create local databse and insert data to local db.

Through server we can perform CRUD operation to remote databse.This will throw lock error. For crud operation we using simple UI IN browser.

Comment: @user734344: still means zero.

Comment: My modules are TouchServer,ThouchStation and TouchAdmin.server is console, station is windows and admin is web form just flex program.station communicate to server to create local db.admin performs crud operation to remote db through server. so both station and admin depend on server.both calls same functionality in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read http://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html?

Also read: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2775595/sqlite-multi-process-access